# how to make a plot by group

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data looks like this:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

and I would like to make a plot by color. Sth looks like this:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

where the doses are the Groups(A,B,..) and constipation, etc are colors (Green, Yellow, Red), mild,moderate, etc are realy_love:Y, N.
How should I do?

if I want to stack Y and N together with different color, will that doable? Can't find a sample picture for that. Hopefully you can get what I said. :P

The codes for creating sample data are:

```
ID<- c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18")
Group<-c("A","B","C","D","D","D","A","B","D","C","B","D","A","A","C","B","B","B")
Color<-c("Green","Yellow","Red","Red","Red","Yellow","Green","Green","Yellow","Red","Red","Yellow","Yellow","Yellow","Green","Red","Red","Green")
Realy_Love<-c("Y","N","Y","Y","N","N","Y","Y","Y","N","N","Y","N","Y","N","Y","N","Y")
Sample.data <- data.frame(ID, Group, Color, Realy_Love)

Sample<-Sample.data %>%
    count(Group, Color, Realy_Love, sort = TRUE)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be we need `facet_wrap`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
Sample.data %>%
 count(Group, Color, Realy_Love, sort = TRUE) %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x = Group, y = n, fill = Realy_Love)) + 
        geom_col(position = 'dodge') + 
        facet_wrap(~ Color)
```

Comment: You are fast. Sorry, I just updated the question.  Add a layer of "Y/N"  in each color. What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: @Stataq the facets are based on 'Color' or "Really_Love"

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I made a little change on yours and it works now ``` Sample.data %>%
+  count(Group, Color, Realy_Love, sort = TRUE) %>% 
+    ggplot(aes(x = Group, y = n, fill =Realy_Love )) + 
+         geom_col(position = 'dodge') + 
+         facet_wrap(~ Color) ```. Is it possible to keep the bin at the same size even when only Y or N in it? Is it possible to stack Yand N in one bin with different color?

Comment: @Stataq You meant `position = 'stack'`